# php code to push conditional values in to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have variables with values:

```
$abc = 'Y';

$xyz = 'N';

$pqr = 'Y';

$lmn = 'Y';
```

I want to create all the variables with value `'Y'` in to an array, similar to as below:

```
$result = ( abc, pqr, lmn)
```

Comment: Seems like some 'jugaad' to me. Explain the full problem.

Comment: You want a result with three `Y` values in an array? Why?

Comment: I think he wants to put names of the variables into an array.

Comment: How is the code supposed to work? I mean if you hard code `if($abc == "Y")` then you already know the variable is called `abc`. So how is the code set up?

Comment: so what's the problem? why can't you do `$result = array($abc, $pqr, $lmn);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For start, collect all your variables to an array:

```
$vars = [
  'abc' => $abc,
  'xyz' => $xyz,
  'pqr' => $pqr,
  'lmn' => $lmn
];
```

Or `$vars = compact('abc','xyz','prq','lmn');`, as `@NiettheDarkAbsol` suggested.

Now you can filter them easy:

```
$result = array_filter($vars, function($a){return $a == 'Y';});

var_dump(array_keys($result)); // ['abc', 'pqr', 'lmn']
```

Comment: An alternative way to define `$vars` would be: `$vars = compact('abc','xyz','prq','lmn')` - it will give the same result but in a more compact way (hurr puns)

Comment: I write this way with hope OP will think about use array **instead** of bunch of variables.